# How to transform an equirectangular (360 degree) video to normal field of view

Tags: panoramas, panorama-control, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama

I am working on 360 degree videos, where I need to render a equirectangular video format in a normal 2D field of view, given any latitude and longitude coordinates in the sphere, just like what 360 degree player does, but control it with code and not by mouse interactions.
So my question is

1. How can I orient the virtual camera in that sphere with code (python preferred) given input as equirectangular video format, so that I can get the image of that particular angle in that sphere.
2. In order to do above, what sort of transformation operations are required to be performed on input video (equirectangular format), so that I can get the cropped normal field of view where virtual camera is oriented.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please read over how to post a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).